# Laravel model ID null after save (ID is incrementing)

Tags: php, mysql, laravel-5, eloquent

I have a save method where I do validation, create a model and save it. Later in the save method I try and access the ID of the model and it's NULL.

Schema:

```
public function up()
{
    Schema::create('posts', function (Blueprint $table) {
        $table->increments('id');
        $table->string('title');
        $table->string('body');
        //and other fields that aren't important right now
        $table->timestamps();
    });
}
```

Save method:

```
public function savePost(Request $request) {

    $this->validate($request, [
        //some validation happens here
    ]);

    $post = new Post();
    $title = $request->input('title');
    $body = $request->input('body');

    $post->title = $title;
    $post->body = $body;

    $post->save();

    //I later try to access the $post->id here and it's still NULL.
    var_dump($post->id);//NULL
}
```

In MySQL the ID is being set (just an auto incrementing unsigned integer) - it seems like it gets set after the savePost method is complete.

I thought that after `$post->save()` was complete, the model's ID would be set - but that seems to not be the case. How can I access the model's ID from the same method where I `save()` it? Or have I made a mistake somewhere?

Laravel Framework version is 5.3.26

Edit: just to clarify: the model (including the auto incrementing PK) is being stored in MySQL, I'm just not able to access the model's id in the same method that I save it.

Answer (score 11, accepted):

Figured it out:

I ran into this issue when switching from a string PK to an auto incrementing unsigned int.

I still had `public $incrementing = false;` in the `Post` model, which explains this issue. Switching to `$incrementing = true` solved the problem.

Comment: Thank you @Chris, that saved me some head-scratching!

Answer (score 3):

For other developers who are using `Pivot/Junction` table, if your model is extending `Pivot` instead of `Model` then this is why.

As @noob mentioned, You've to enable `public $incrementing = true;` manually or just extend `Model` instead.

Comment: This was my problem. I copied and pasted from another pivot model and couldn't figure out why it wasn't populating the id field after save. Thank you!